# Can you use psmpy to match groups on an ordinal variable?

Tags: python, statistics, propensity-score-matching

I am using psmpy to propensity score match groups. One variable I am matching is a binned value of income (ex. 3 = $12,000 - $15,999, 4 = $16,00 - $24,999, etc.). When I include this income variable in the Propensity score matching, and compare the resulting 4 groups with an ANOVA, the income is matched. However, because the income bins are an ordinal variable not continuous, I am pretty sure they need to be compared with a Chi-squared test of association not an ANOVA. When I compare the four groups with the Chi-squared test, the groups are not matched on income.

Is there a better way to include this binned income variable in propensity score matching? Or is an ANOVA an acceptable way to compare the groups on this measure?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but here's what I do:
when I do Propensity Score Matching and my confounding variables are categorical (binned variables in your case), I convert them to binary variables using Pandas function `get_dummies` prior to matching control to a treatment group:

`import Pandas as pd`

`df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns = ['Income'], dtype = float)`